# function called on click not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Function isn't called when I click on the button.

```
<script>
    $(function() {

    var reset = function () {
    obj.x = canvas.width / 2;
    obj.y = canvas.height / 2;

    };
    });
  </script>
  <input type="button" onclick="reset();" />
```

Why ?

Comment: Because the `scope` of function is not `global`

Comment: Of course, you made that function private in an IIFE...

Comment: Why is your button inside your `<script>`?

Comment: @Tushar But if I make this function as global, I wil not see canvas

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just [move `reset` declaration out of function](https://jsfiddle.net/e99ncb7a/), because javascript handlers need to be declared in global scope.

Comment: Link-only answer, probably.

Answer (score 3):

As was already said in comment, your `reset` function is in a local scope, which makes it invisible from the global scope (where you set the `onclick`).

And it's fine, really, it's good not to declare a bunch of functions in the global scope.

The solution here is to properly attach the event handler:

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
          var reset = function () {
          obj.x = canvas.width / 2;
          obj.y = canvas.height / 2;
       }
       document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', reset);
    });
  </script>
  <input type="button" id=myButton/>
```

Or, as you seem to use jQuery :

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
          var reset = function () {
          obj.x = canvas.width / 2;
          obj.y = canvas.height / 2;
       }
       $('#myButton').click(reset);
    });
  </script>
  <input type="button" id=myButton/>
```